# Power BI Matrix how to calculate remain onhand for each month?

Tags: powerbi

Sample data.
i need to mark power bi report for on hand remain for each month. by using sales forecast.
but still not finished.

in reporting service we can use code for calculate like this. i don't know power bi do.

Power BI Matrix how to calculate  remain on hand for each month?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkkPV.png)

i try to use calculate column but it don't work.